# The scales in Y-axis in proportional geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand why this plot doesn't show the proportions correctly.

The Y-axis keeps showing scales that aren't proportional (whole numbers instead of fractions)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_bar(aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., fill=color, group=color))

> head(diamonds, 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 10
carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
<dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
```

Comment: we need the rawdata for it

Comment: We have it -- `diamonds` is included in ggplot2.

Comment: @Sima, welcome to SO, could you put results of head(diamonds,10) in question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `group = 1` instead of `group = color`. You'll also need to color it differently (as `fill = color` will not work).

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..), group = 1))
```

[image: pic]

There is more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063362/how-to-color-bar-plots-when-using-prop-in-ggplot).