# Error in ggplot2 when using both fill and group parameters in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

There seems to be a problem with R's `ggplot2` library when I include both the fill and group parameters in a bar plot (`geom_bar()`). I've already tried looking for answers for several hours but couldn't find one that would help. This is actually my first post here.

To give a little background, I have a dataframe named `smokement` (short for smoke and mental health), a categorical variable named `smoke100` (smoked in the past 100 days?) with "Yes" and "No", and another categorical variable named `misnervs` (frequency of feelings of nervousness) with 5 possible values: "All", "Most", "Some", "A little", and "None."

When I run this code, I get this result:

```
ggplot(data = smokement) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, fill = smoke100)) + 
facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image: First code output]

However, the result I want is to have all grouped bar plots display their respective proportions. By reading a bit of "R for Data Science" book I found out that I need to include `y = ..prop..` and `group = 1` in `aes()` to achieve it:

```
ggplot(data = smokement) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, y = ..prop.., group = 1)) + 
facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image: Second code output]

Finally, I try to use the `fill = smoke100` parameter in `aes()` to display this categorical variable in color, just like I did on the first code. But when I add this fill parameter, it doesn't work! The code runs, but it shows exactly the same output as the second code, as if the fill parameter this time was somehow ignored!

```
ggplot(data = smokement) +
geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, y = ..prop.., group = 1, fill = smoke100)) +
facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image: Third code output]

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens, and how to solve it? My end goal is to display each value of smoke100 (the "Yes" and "No" bars) with colors and a legend at the right, just like on the first graph, while having each grouping level of "misnervs" display their respective proportions of smoke100 ("Yes", "No") levels, just like on the second graph.

EDIT:

```
> dim(smokement)
[1] 35471     6
> str(smokement)
'data.frame':   35471 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ smoke100: Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ misnervs: Factor w/ 5 levels "All","Most","Some",..: 3 4 5 4 1 5 3 3 5 5 ...
 $ mishopls: Factor w/ 5 levels "All","Most","Some",..: 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ misrstls: Factor w/ 5 levels "All","Most","Some",..: 3 5 5 3 1 5 3 5 1 5 ...
 $ misdeprd: Factor w/ 5 levels "All","Most","Some",..: 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ miswtles: Factor w/ 5 levels "All","Most","Some",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
> head(smokement)
  smoke100 misnervs mishopls misrstls misdeprd miswtles
1      Yes     Some     Some     Some     None     None
2       No A little     None     None     None     None
3      Yes     None     None     None     None     None
4       No A little     None     Some     None     None
5      Yes      All     None      All A little     None
6      Yes     None     None     None     None     None
```

As for the output without `group = 1`

```
ggplot(data = smokement) +
+ geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, y = ..prop.., fill = smoke100)) +
+ facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image: No group code output]

Comment: Can you run `dput(smokement)`  and paste it the output in your question so we can get an idea of what your data looks like?

Comment: What happens if you remove `group=1` from your final attempt?

Comment: @neuron @Limey  I sadly can't put the whole output of `dput()` because the dataset is 30 thousands rows long and won't fit it all, but I've included these function outputs if it helps. I will also include the output of removing `group = 1`. I'm going to edit my question so I can post another picture and show the function outputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to color bar plots when using ..prop.. in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063362/how-to-color-bar-plots-when-using-prop-in-ggplot)

Comment: @stefan it appears that this question is a sort of duplicate; we were facing almost the same issue. I did check about 7 different questions here before posting to avoid duplicating questions, I didn't see that one being asked, probably because I was searching for `group` together with `fill`. I'm glad you answered this question anyways! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063868/12993861) the `GGAlly` package includes a `stat_prop` which introduces a new `by` aesthetic to specify the way the proportions should be calculated:

```r
library(GGally)

ggplot(data = smokement) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, y = ..prop.., fill = smoke100, by = misnervs), stat = "prop") + 
  facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

And just for reference the same could be achieved without `GGAlly` by setting `fill=factor(..x..)`:

```r
ggplot(data = smokement) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = smoke100, y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..), group = 1)) + 
  facet_wrap(~misnervs, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
misnervs <- c("All", "Most", "Some", "A little", "None")

set.seed(123)

smokement <- 
  data.frame(
    smoke100 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    misnervs = factor(sample(misnervs, 100, replace = TRUE), levels = misnervs)
  )
```

Comment: I tried both versions of your solution and they work wonderfully, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! This problem was giving me a tough time.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get what you wanted by tweaking your call to `geom_bar`*, but I think this gives you what you are looking for.  As you didn't provide your input dataset (for understandable reasons), I've used the `diamonds` tibble in my code.  The changes you need to make should be obvious.

*:  I'm sure it *can* be done: I just wasn't able to work it out.

The idea behind my solution is to pre-compute the proportions you want to plot before the call to `ggplot`.

`group_modify` takes a grouped tibble and applies the specified function to each group in turn, before returning the modified (grouped) tibble.

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
    group_modify(
      function(.x, .y) 
        .x %>% 
        group_by(color) %>% 
        summarise(Prop=n()/nrow(.))
    ) %>% 
    ggplot() +
      geom_col(aes(x=color, y=Prop, fill=color)) +
      facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image]
Note the switch from `geom_bar` to `geom_col`: `geom_bar` uses row counts, `geom_col` uses values in the data.

As a rough-and-ready QC, here's the equivalent of your code that produces the "all grey' plot:

```
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=color, y=..prop.., fill=color, group=1)) +
    facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! It makes sense to work the problem around that way. I thought about trying something similar but my knowledge in R is still fairly poor, so I wasn't able to pull it off. I'm glad I now have some code to tweak with.